# Select XMLNode by Id using XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the below fragement of XML, notice that the Reference node holds a URI which links to the Id attribute of the Body node.

```
 <Reference URI="#Body">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body Id="Body" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.dingo.org">
    <ns0:Add xmlns:ns0="http://www.moo.com">
      <ns0:a>2</ns0:a>
      <ns0:b>3</ns0:b>
    </ns0:Add>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

If I had the value of the URI attribute how would I then get the whole Body XMLNode? I presume this would be best done via an XPath epression but haven't any clue on XPath. Note that the XML will not always be so simple.  I'm doing this in c# btw :)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jon

EDIT: I wouldn't know the XML structure or namespaces before hand, all I would know is that the reference element has the ID of the xmlNode i want to retrieve, hope this is sligtly clearer.

Comment: Is the value of `URI` attribute on `<Reference>` element (which, I assume, is what you refer to) always going to be of the form `"#ID"`, and nothing else?

Comment: Is the Reference element the root element? Will it always be? Will there always be only one Reference element? Will there only ever be one element whose Id attribute matches the Reference element's URI attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a condition that applies to a relative (or absolute node) to any step of an XPath expression.

In this case:

```
//*[@id=substring-after(/Reference/@URI, '#')]
```

The `//*` matches all elements in the document. The part in `[]` is a condition. Inside the condition the part of the URI element of the root References node is taken, but ignoring the '#' (and anything before it).

Sample code, assuming you have loaded your XML into `XPathDocument` `doc`:

```
var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
var found = nav.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=substring-after(/Reference/@URI, '#')]");
```

Comment: sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean, I also wouldn't know the XML structure before hand, basically I recieve this XML and need to get the node referenced by the URI attribute in the Reference tag

Answer (score 1):

If you have the value of the URI attribute in a variable you could use

```
myXmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//SOAP-ENV:Body[ID='pURI']")
```

where pURI is the value of the URI attribute and myXmlDocument is the Xml Document object

Comment: You need to add a namespace mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
XmlDocument requestDocument = new XmlDocument();
requestDocument.LoadXml(yourXmlString);
String someXml = requestDocument.SelectSingleNode(@"/*[local-name()='Reference ']/*[local-name()='Body']").InnerXml;
```

Comment: "SOAP-ENV" is the namespace tag, not the local name.

Comment: I wouldn't know the xml strucutre or namespaces before hand though, see my edit