# XPath in PHP - Find in Document Specific Element with Id

Tags: php, html, xpath

everyone.

I have an HTML document that contains a very-nested element with a unique ID.

Can XPath find this element? I want to print its inner text.

If not, what do I have to specify? Location in document, tag, etc.?

I've tried to build some queries, but they don't work. I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing.

I'm a bit rusty with XPath, so explanations on how it works would be useful.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Gal.

Comment: Please read help section on how to ask questions, thank you

Comment: check answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698409/phpunit-selenium2-not-returning-text/27056153#27056153

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select XMLNode by Id using XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496850/select-xmlnode-by-id-using-xpath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Can XPath find this element?"*

Yes it can. Without further details on the context, We can only suggest something like this :

```
//*[@id='your_unique_id_value_here']
```

The above XPath means, find all elements (should be only one anyway since `id` is unique as you described), whatever its name, where `id` attribute value equals `"your_unique_id_value_here"`.

More introductory explanations on XPath : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath